# WooCommerce filter products by range

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For example I have two variations, 'from_year' and 'until_year', how can I filtering products by range in product archive page.

If to call this url, will get only products that equals to the variables, but need `from_year >= 2005` and `until_year <= 20015`

> mysite.com/?from_year=2005&until_year=2015&post_type=product

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create the url for the link or how to get the combination of terms?

Comment: get the combination of terms

Answer (score 0):

you need date queries. Here's a good tutorial on [date queries](http://www.viper007bond.com/2013/08/27/date-queries-in-wordpress-3-point-7/) and here's the Codex on [date parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) for `WP_Query`.

You will also need to filter [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) to add your new query variables and [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify the posts retrieved based on your new query vars.

With all that reference material, here's my attempt at how this should be done.

```
// Add query vars for filtering by years
function so_33714675_add_vars($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'from_year';
    $query_vars[] = 'until_year';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'so_33714675_add_vars' );

// Filter product arvhice if query vars are present
function so_33714675_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && is_shop() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $from_year = get_query_var('from_year');
        $until_year = get_query_var('until_year');

        $date_query = array();

        if( ! empty( $from_year ) ){
            $date_query['after'] = array(
                'year'      => $from_year,
            );
        } 

        if( ! empty( $until_year ) ){
            $date_query['before'] = array(
                'year'      => $until_year,
            );

        } 

        // order by date
        if( ! empty( $date_query ) ){
             set_query_var( 'orderby', 'date' );
             set_query_var( 'order', 'ASC' );

             $date_query['inclusive'] = true;
             set_query_var( 'date_query', array( $date_query ) );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_33714675_pre_get_posts' );
```

Keep in mind that this is not fully tested. I'm 99% positive this is the correct approach, but it may need some tweaking.

Comment: Hi, I no need filter posts by date range, but this may help, thanks.
I need filter woocommerce products by variable/attribute range.

Comment: I see you have edited your question to make this more clear. but now it is a completely different from what it was before. In the future, please try to have the most accurate question possible.